# DataTable Join all Rows Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, datatable

Actually,I have a `DataTable` containing 2000 rows with a `ColumnName` `EMAIL`.
Now,I want to show all emails from the `DataTable` and adding them to a `TextBox` by separating with a `,`.

I am achieving this by a `for` loop,But,it is taking a long time.

Actually,I have used for getting the `ColumnNames` :

```
string[] columnNames1 = (from dc in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                                select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Is there any thing like this,for `joining` all rows data to a single string ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var text = string.Join(",", table.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Select(x=>x["EMAIL"].ToString())
                                 .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose any one value is NULL means, Get the NULL Object reference error occurs

```
var text=string.Join(",", table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
x["EMAIL"].ToString()).ToArray());
```

so check the field value and after that you add the values

```
var text=string.Join(",", table.AsEnumerable().Select(x => 
((x["EMAIL"]) ? x["EMAIL"] : "").ToString()));
```

Comment: what is ColumnName here ?

Comment: ColumnName is your field name "EMail" @RealSteel